# JMeter console execution exclude all logs(log, System.out, println) except summary

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-logging

I created a basic HttpRequest call in Jmeter (GET https:[www.google.com](http://www.google.com)) with a JSR223 PostProcessor with the following code(this is just an example):

```
log.info("log");
System.out.println("Sysout");
println("println");
```

When I run the performance test via command line with the following command:

```
jmeter -n -t example.jmx -l ./example.log -e -o ./html_report -Lorg=FATAL
```

I can make `log.info("log")` to not be printed to the console (thanks to the param `-Lorg=FATAL`), but the other two entries (`Sysout` and `println`) keep being printed.

My goal is to just print the summary data in the console without any entry (log, print, system.out) to be printed (so I can monitor the progress), my expected output would be:

```
Starting standalone test @ Wed Mar 09 11:03:34 EST 2022 (1646841814615)
Waiting for possible Shutdown/StopTestNow/HeapDump/ThreadDump message on port 4445
summary =     10 in 00:00:12 =    0.8/s Avg:  1224 Min:   979 Max:  3247 Err:     0 (0.00%)
Tidying up ...    @ Wed Mar 09 11:03:47 EST 2022 (1646841827566)
... end of run
```

**How can I disable the other outputs?**

**Note**: Disabling/commenting the code lines is not allowed of course

Answer (score 0):

If you are not interested in jmeter.log file at all you can turn off all logging completely and leave only [Summariser](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/reporters/Summariser.html) class

In *log4j2.xml* file:

1. Change [line 51](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.4.3/bin/log4j2.xml#L51) from `<Root level="info">` to `<Root level="Off">`
2. Add `<Logger name="org.apache.jmeter.reporters" level="info"/>` line to `<Loggers>` section
3. Optionally you can comment out or delete all other entries in `<Loggers` section

Full *log4j2.xml* file just in case:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN" packages="org.apache.jmeter.gui.logging">

  <Appenders>
    <File name="jmeter-log" fileName="${sys:jmeter.logfile:-jmeter.log}" append="false">
      <PatternLayout>
        <pattern>%d %p %c{1.}: %m%n</pattern>
      </PatternLayout>
    </File>

    <GuiLogEvent name="gui-log-event">
      <PatternLayout>
        <pattern>%d %p %c{1.}: %m%n</pattern>
      </PatternLayout>
    </GuiLogEvent>

  </Appenders>

  <Loggers>

    <Root level="Off">
      <AppenderRef ref="jmeter-log" />
      <AppenderRef ref="gui-log-event" />
    </Root>

    <Logger name="org.apache.jmeter.reporters" level="info"/>

  </Loggers>

</Configuration>
```

This way the [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) will only contain the "summary" of your test execution.

More information: [How to Configure JMeter Logging](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging)

There is no way to play this trick with the [STDOUT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_(stdout)), you can either disable it completely or have everything, however you can filter the output using i.e. [grep](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html) command

Comment: as mentioned, I was able to get rid off the LOG messages, println and system.out were my issue

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer by myself, since `STDOUT` is something I cannot get rid off in a selective way(and apparently `println` neither) I just `grep` the output:

```
jmeter -n -t example.jmx -l ./example.log -e -o ./html_report -Lorg=FATAL | grep 'summary\|Tidying\|end'
```

and this is my output

```
Creating summariser <summary>
summary +      7 in 00:00:12 =    0.6/s Avg:  1669 Min:   620 Max:  6131 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 1 Started: 1 Finished: 0
summary +     31 in 00:00:30 =    1.0/s Avg:   976 Min:   270 Max:  1052 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 1 Started: 1 Finished: 0
summary =     38 in 00:00:43 =    0.9/s Avg:  1104 Min:   270 Max:  6131 Err:     0 (0.00%)
summary +     12 in 00:00:12 =    1.0/s Avg:   993 Min:   812 Max:  1051 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 0 Started: 1 Finished: 1
summary =     50 in 00:00:55 =    0.9/s Avg:  1077 Min:   270 Max:  6131 Err:     0 (0.00%)
Tidying up ...    @ Wed Mar 09 11:29:12 EST 2022 (1646843352418)
... end of run
```

cheers!!